# aiptek graphics tablet not working on 17.10

Tags: gnome, xorg, input-devices, graphics-tablet

I have an old Trust/Aiptek tablet which is correctly identified in `dmesg`

```
[    7.047168] aiptek 1-1:1.0: Aiptek using 400 ms programming speed
[    7.047230] input: Aiptek as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:03:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input7
[    7.047335] usbcore: registered new interface driver aiptek
```

I installed `xserver-xorg-input-aiptek` and created the configuration file for `Xorg`

**`/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-aiptek.conf`**

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Aiptek class"
        MatchProduct "Aiptek|AIPTEK|aiptek"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "aiptek"
        Option "USB" "on"
        Option "Type" "stylus"
        Option "Mode" "absolute"
        Option "zMin" "0"
        Option "zMax" "511"
EndSection
```

Now it works on the login screen (`GDM`) but it stops working as soon as I login to `GNOME` (vanilla session, ubuntu 17.10).

Any idea? looks like a permission problem but there's not much to look for online as it's a pretty old device

Comment: The same on Ubuntu 18.04, except it does not even work on gdm. Ubuntu 16.04 is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed, it is a permission problem, quite irrelevant to the fact that this is an old device.

Simply add yourself to the `input` group, like this

```
sudo usermod -a -G input yourusername
```

At least this is what was needed to get this device working under Ubuntu 18.04 (Xorg)